# Help a misunderstood Bayesian mathematician

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'm a mathematician-turned-physician and I'm currently taking a Genetics course. Some high-school level probability is usually covered in these courses and it would be expected that lecturers that are not mathematicians/statisticians may not fully comprehend what they are talking about.

The lecturer responsible for writing and grading exams made an inaccurate assertion and when I tried to make my case, she doubled down, claiming the answer depends on how ones sees it. Not the reply that a mathematician would like to hear but here we are. The problem is (sorry if I'm defining very simple terms/concepts):

It is given that an individual can have 4 equiprobable genotypes: $AA$, $Aa$, $aA$ and $aa$, where $A$ is the good/normal allele and $a$ is the defective allele. For completeness, we all carry 2 copies of the same gene/allele for all autosomal chromosomes (one we inherited from mom and the other from dad). Considering an autosomal recessive condition, *i.e.*, the individual has the condition when both alleles are defective -- the $aa$ genotype -- what is the probability that the individual is a carrier, *i.e.*, it would be possible for the individual to pass the defective allele forward to her progeny --  given that she is not affected, *i.e.*, she does not have the $aa$ genotype. Moreover, do we need to apply Bayes' Theorem somehow to arrive at this conclusion (even if it is a very straightforward application)?

Edit: It is clear that the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$. This is not in contention. She claimed that **"we did not need Bayes' Theorem" or any knowledge of conditional probability whatsoever** to arrive at that conclusion. This is false as the moment we are restricting the sample space we are implicitly calculating a conditional probability, which would imply Bayesian reasoning, even if we do it without noticing it. It is a subtle point but it is an important one. ***I wondered whether other mathematicians/statisticians would agree with me...*** Formal solution below.

Comment: Hi, welcome. What did the lecturer say the answer was and what do you think it is? I was able to answer the question for myself without any appeal to Bayes.

Comment: I am not a Bayesian mathematician, nor a physician, and I would say: $2/3$. But the answer is entirely in your sentence: "can have $4$ _equiprobable_ genotypes: $AA, Aa, aA$ and $aa$".

Comment: The question could be made clearer and more interesting if you also include the "inaccurate assertion" made by the lecture and your reasoning against it.

Comment: Something is off about the statement. You say assume the individual has the condition (aa) and then ask what is the probability that she doesn't? Is the question what the probability that someone without the condition is a carrier, or something else?

Comment: Are the four allele pairs really equiprobable? 25% of the population is assumed to have the condition?

Comment: Equiprobable in genetics means that one's offspring would have the same probability of inheriting each of the 4 allele combinations ($AA$, $aA$, $Aa$ and $aa$). The offspring will only have the disease if the $aa$ allele is inherited if we are talking about an autosomal recessive condition.

Comment: Okay, well in this case I do agree that Bayes theorem is not necessary, especially given the equiprobabilty assumption, but using the language of conditional probability makes the logic clearer.

Comment: Seems it is just a counting problem, since you said equiprobable. Only 3 balls in the urn now, 2 of which lead to being a carrier. Probability of picking one of those two. Concur that it can be cast as a Bayesian problem, albeit at a cost of added unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip That's exactly my point. How can one use conditional probability without evoking Bayes' Theorem, which *defined* conditional probability?

Comment: And my point is that someone who had never heard of conditional probability or Bayes' Theorem could solve this question  simply by reasoning it through.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes but the fact that one may not know anything about Bayesian statistics does not change the fact they are using it.

Comment: meh, I think you're just trying to score rhetorical points over your lecturer on a relatively meaningless question.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip It's not rhetorical; there's not rhetoric in mathematics; this is not social studies. She is actually asking questions like this ("Bayesian" or not?) and is has not been grading them correctly. I couldn't care less about what she thinks about it as long as it doesn't interfere with everybody else's grades (other students agreed with me; I'm the only mathematician in class).

Answer (score 3):

According to your problem statement, AA, Aa, aA and aa are equiprobable a priori, -- i.e. relative likelihood 1 : 1 : 1 : 1.  Given the new information that "the person is not affected -- i.e. homozygous recessive aa", we now have relative likelihoods 1 : 1 : 1 : 0.

So AA, Aa, aA are equally likely and there is a $2/3$ chance that the person is a carrier.

Comment: Your answer is correct; I'd just like to point out that the person is **not** affected, hence we restrict our sample space to $AA$, $Aa$ and $aA$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formal Bayesian solution (unnecessary, really, because the problem is very simple.)

Let $C$ correspond to the event that the individual is a carrier, *i.e.*, she carries at least one deleterious allele and let $H$ correspond to the event that the individual is healthy, *i.e.*, she does not have the disease. We are interested in calculating the probability $P(C|H)$. Applying Bayes' Theorem:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(C|H) & = & \frac{P(C \cap H)}{P(H)} \\
&  = & \frac{P(H|C) P(C)}{P(H)} \\
& = & \frac{P(H|C) P(C)}{P(H|C) P(C) + P(H|\bar{C}) P(\bar{C})}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\bar{C}$ corresponds to the event that the individual does not harbor any deleterious allele.

The unconditional probabilities $P(C)$ and $P(\bar{C})$ are trivial: $P(C) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(\bar{C}) = \frac{1}{4}$. The conditional probabilities $P(H|C)$ and $P(H|\bar{C})$ are also trivial: $P(H|C) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(H|\bar{C}) = 1$. Plugging all the numbers:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(C|H) & = & \frac{P(H|C) P(C)}{P(H|C) P(C) + P(H|\bar{C}) P(\bar{C})} \\
& = & \frac{\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{3}{4}}{\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{3}{4} + 1 \times \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{2}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}